# how to Insert data from Online MySQL database to Local MySQL datatable Frequently using sql query?

Tags: mysql, database, vb6

I have to MySQl databases, 1st is online hosted named **onlinedb**, and second is on local machine(localhost) named **localdb**, now i want to insert online database's data to my local host's database table **frequently and as per user request**, and i am using **VB6** for my application. so how can i do it using query?

My destination and source database are on different location, destination database is on local host, and source database is online hosted on server.

I have tried this query, but it is not working.

Query:

```
"INSERT INTO localdb.mytable SELECT * FROM onlinedb.mytable  WHERE mytable.Id=0"
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make a dump on your online machine using `mysqldump`and import this dump on your local machine.

Comment: But in my system, i have to perform this operations Frequently, so is is proper to make dump all the time, is there any other way?

Comment: If you need to make this operation more frequently, I suggest you update your question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MySQL Dump Command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html)

So, for instance

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword myDatabase | mysql -hremoteserver
-uremoteuser -premoteserver
```

Answer (score 0):

Are this DDBBs using the same ports?

I suggest you to import /export .SQL but, nevertheless you can copy tables from differents databases using this:

```
SELECT *

INTO newtable [IN externaldb] FROM table1;
```

> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Comment: yes bot are use same port, but one is online and second is on localhost.

Comment: so create a SSH tunnel to redirect it to other port

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *  INTO DestinationDatabase..DestTable FROM SourceDataBase..SourceTable
```

or

```
INSERT INTO DestinationDataBase..DestTable SELECT * FROM SourceDataBase..SourceTable
```

Comment: my destination and sourse database are on different location, destination database is on local host, and sourse database is online hosted on server. so how can i do it?